# Python3.4 Py2exe, error - name 'WinDLL' is not defined

Tags: python, py2exe

I use Ubuntu, Python 3.4 and try to compile my py scripts to exe using [py2exe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0).

Unfortunately When I try to use command 'build_exe', it generates error!
Could anybody help me to solve it or advise how to compile py project to exe in another way?

Error code:

`NameError: name 'WinDLL' is not define`.

[image]

Comment: -1 for linking to a screen shot instead of simply pasting the error text.

Comment: ok, I have inserted the error, however it is also in the header

Answer (score 6):

py2exe is for windows...

On linux you can try **PyInstaller**:
http://www.pyinstaller.org/

> PyInstaller is now able to build Windows executables when running
>   under Linux. See documentation for more details.

Comment: PyInstaller Unfortunately does not support Python 3.4

Comment: @CodeNinja, maybe i didn't get it but the tool's FAQ says that you can't package windows binaries while running under linux.
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ


the cross compiling you pointed out is a dead link now... 

 
http://www.pyinstaller.org/browser/tags/1.4/doc/CHANGES.txt

Answer (score 0):

The ***py2exe* module needs to be run from within a command prompt shell (aka Windows terminal) to make a Windows executable**, since just like *pyinstaller*, "[they use the OS support to load the dynamic libraries, thus ensuring full compatibility](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)". That's why you get the ''WinDLL' is not defined' error when using the *py2exe* module in a bash shell.

*py2exe* works until python-3.4 and *pyinstaller* works until python-3.7. The latest version at time of writing is 3.8. Use the python module ***virtualenv*** from command prompt to get the adeqaute python version running (without replacing your current python set-up), and make your executable file. [Here is my answer with code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63725687/12488039). --> Make sure to add python to your Windows path on install, so you can use the **pip** and **python** commands in command prompt. Otherwise you have to replace these commands in my answer for their fullpath, e.g. C:\Users\jakethefinn\python37\pip.exe and C:\Users\jakethefinn\python37\python.exe respectively.
If you install python from Microsoft Store, the files pip.exe and python.exe are automatically added to path.