# converting .py to .exe using Python 3.5/3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

I created an application in Python 3.6 with a GUI built in PyQt5. Some modules are only available for Python 3.5 and 3.6.
I managed to pack it on Mac using py2app. I am trying to do the same thing on Windows. I tried to use [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/best-method-of-converting-py-to-exe-for-python-3-6), but I still have issues.
For what I understand I have 3 options:

1. py2exe
2. pyinstaller
3. cx_Freeze

**1) py2exe**

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578808/python-indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range-when-using-py2exe) py2exe is still not available for python3.6, I need to use python3.5 then.

Using 3.5, I get this error and the compilation stops:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\carlo\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python35\\site-packages\\py2exe\\run-py3.5-win32.exe'
```

**2) pyinstaller**
Running pyinstaller through Python3.5 as:
`pyinstaller --onefile APP.py`

I get just a bunch of warnings (lib not found) but the compilation gets to the end. The created EXE, though, opens the command prompt and pops up the following error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 573, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt5plugins
```

**3) cx_Freeze**
Using python3.5, it first give the 'TCL_LIBRARY' error. Following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533803/keyerror-tcl-library-when-i-use-cx-freeze) the compilation goes smoothly. The created application, however, opens up and closes immediately. It simply doesn't work.
Using python3.6, the compilation seems okay. When I try to open the application, this error pops up. I just managed to take a quick [screen-shot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7etnA.png)

Does anybody have any suggestion? Any alternative I am not considering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem!
I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2402).
I first ran (with Python3.5):

`pyinstaller CodeName.py`

Then I modified the .spec file as indicated in the [link](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2402) and the magic happened!