# Creating an executable from python file

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, executable, py2exe, python-3.8

I need to make an executable out of a .py file. I looked into it and tried:

1. py2exe -> this doesn't work with python3.8 (gives me "IndexError: tuple index out of range")
2. pyinstaller -> still doesn't work (TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes))

For pyinstaller I might have found a solution [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4265) but still doesn't work for me. (a user said to use the latest version compatible with 3.8 -> pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz

Any alternative solution / fix would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This subject has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578808/python-indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range-when-using-py2exe)

The latest release of Py2exe (0.9.2.2) was built for Python 3.4 and will not work in 3.7+.

There is a Github project that is porting Py2exe to 3.7 ([link here](https://github.com/albertosottile/py2exe)). I made some tests with Python 3.7 and it works well to generate exe files.