# Hello world example for py2exe giving strange error

Tags: python, py2exe

I have a file named "mini.py" with the following contents:

```
print("hello worlds")
```

If I run `pip install py2exe --upgrade` I get:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: py2exe in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (0.9.2.2)
```

If I run `build_exe mini.py` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python37\Scripts\build_exe.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 141, in main
    builder.analyze()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 160, in analyze
    self.mf.import_hook(modname)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
    self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 388, in _scan_code
    for what, args in self._scan_opcodes(code):
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 417, in _scan_opcodes
    yield "store", (names[oparg],)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Anyone has any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, a duplicate of [Python - IndexError: tuple index out of range when using py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578808/python-indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range-when-using-py2exe)

Py2exe 0.9.2.2 works with Python up to 3.4, and the development stoped there.

For Python 3.7 there is a project in GithUb porting Py2Exe, that works fine. https://github.com/albertosottile/py2exe