# Python 'py2exe' not working after following the tutorial

Tags: python, py2exe

I am trying to follow py2exe tutorial with 'Hello World' but run into errors. Here are my steps.
Created `hello.py` as below:

```
print ('Hello World!')
```

Made sure it works:

```
D:\Users\test>python hello.py
Hello World!
```

Created `setup.py` as instructed:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

Run dos command:

```
D:\Users\test>python setup.py install
running install
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Python364\Lib\site-packages\UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Python364\Lib\site-packages\UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.6.egg-info
D:\Users\test>
```

Then run another DOS command:

```
D:\Users\test>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup(console=['hello.py'])
  File "C:\Python364\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python364\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python364\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python364\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188,
in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python364\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267,
in _run
    builder.analyze()
  File "C:\Python364\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 160, in analyze
    self.mf.import_hook(modname)
  File "C:\Python364\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
  File "C:\Python364\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
  File "C:\Python364\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_lo
ad
    self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
  File "C:\Python364\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 388, in _scan_code
    for what, args in self._scan_opcodes(code):
  File "C:\Python364\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 417, in _scan_opcode
s
    yield "store", (names[oparg],)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
D:\Users\test>
```

Has anyone run into same situation?

From [Python - IndexError: tuple index out of range when using py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578808/python-indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range-when-using-py2exe), I've had success with a Python 3.6 program using the fork of py2exe at https://github.com/albertosottile/py2exe, comment made by @Rasjid Wilcox, https://github.com/albertosottile/py2exe working for Python 3.6. It works for 32-bit too.