# Can import py2exe at command prompt and in scripts but can't run setup.py at command prompt due to "module not found error."

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm working to take several scripts I've written and create both Mac applications and Windows executables using py2app and py2exe, respectively. I'm doing the Mac work on my own machine and have encountered no problems. For Windows, I'm forced to access my school's computer via Remote Desktop. There I'm using IDLE with Python 3.8 on Windows 10. All python packages are installed by my system administrator.

py2exe has been installed as the picture below shows:

[image]

I'm able to import py2exe at the IDLE shell and import it inside scripts. However, when I try to follow the tutorial at https://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step2 and run the "hello world" example, I encounter a problem. My setup is as shown there:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe 
setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

At the command prompt, I type

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

But I receive the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py2exe' found" error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall python-3.8 and install python-3.4 to get *py2exe* working. Or use the python-module *virtualenv* to keep both versions. [Here is my answer with code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63725687/12488039) on using *virtualenv* to get *py2exe* or *pyinstaller* working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import py2exe in the code

```
Delete
#import py2exe
```

if you want to create exe, go to cmd and
$py2exe

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I've deleted the import command from my setup file as you suggest.

At the prompt, trying both of the following results in error messages:

$py2exe.    (yields unrecognized command)

python setup.py $py2exe (yields invalid command)

If you look at the setup file in the tutorial, you'll see py2exe is imported there.

Comment: use pyinstaller instead, https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html